# PDF (not text) to Speech

Tags: pdf, text-to-speech, ebook-reader

I need a TTS program to read my PDF files. I tried several programs, but all convert PDF to raw text, then read it. My PDF files have lots of pictures and designs, and I need to look at the PDF file when the TTS program is reading the text.

Is there any TTS program to read a PDF file when viewing the original PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF to Speech Pro *https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.practicalapps&hl=en* $2.99.

One of the better ones, actually does what it is suppose to. I haven't came across any free ones.

Comment: I came across this app, but contrary to its name, their videos do not show a PDF to speed, and all videos just show text to speech instead.